# Find index in array of objects with random key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

If I have an array of nested objects with random keys, how can I find the index of an object knowing the random key?

For example index of object with key Jas9d8d?
(Answer would be 0)

```
const myArray = [
    Jas9d8d:{
        151231230123:{
           key1:value
           key2:value
           key3:value},
    },

    gkdkaksd9d:{
        151231230123:{
           key1:value
           key2:value
           key3:value},
    },

    hdhfe89hef:{
        151231230123:{
           key1:value
           key2:value
           key3:value},
    },
]
```

Comment: That's an invalid array object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
const myArray = [{    Jas9d8d: {      '151231230123': {        key1: 'value',        key2: 'value',        key3: 'value'      }    }  },  {    gkdkaksd9d: {      '151231230123': {        key1: 'value',        key2: 'value',        key3: 'value'      }    }  },  {    hdhfe89hef: {      '151231230123': {        key1: 'value',        key2: 'value',        key3: 'value'      }    }  }];

const myObj = myArray.find(x => x.hasOwnProperty("Jas9d8d")) || 0;
// Returns the object that satisfies the test base on the key provided. If not, returns 0.
var myObjIndex = myArray.indexOf(myObj);
```

Note that Array.find() is not supported in IE.

Comment: Question is about index. Use `findIndex` instead.

Comment: I thought this was the simplest solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the structure of that array is valid and every object has only one key-value:**

```js
const myArray = [{    Jas9d8d: {      '151231230123': {        key1: 'value',        key2: 'value',        key3: 'value'      }    }  },  {    gkdkaksd9d: {      '151231230123': {        key1: 'value',        key2: 'value',        key3: 'value'      }    }  },  {    hdhfe89hef: {      '151231230123': {        key1: 'value',        key2: 'value',        key3: 'value'      }    }  }];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (Object.keys(myArray[i]).pop() === 'Jas9d8d') {
    console.log(`Found at index ${i}`);
    break;
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[findIndex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp) was made exactly for this:

```
var i = myArray.findIndex(x => x.hasOwnProperty("Jas9d8d")); // 0
```

If `findIndex` is not supported by your engine, this will work everywhere:

```
var i = myArray.length-1;
for (; i >= 0; --i)
    if (myArray[i].hasOwnProperty("Jas9d8d"))
        break;
console.log(i); // 0
```